# Force landscape orientation for UIWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, swift2, landscape

I have an app where all the views are portraits but only one view which is a UIWebView which loads a PDF needs to be in Landscape.

My project settings are below:

[image]

I have tried the following:

```
 override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
 }

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    let orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask = [UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape, UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeLeft]
    return orientation
}
```

The above code does not seem to be working. I got the code by searching online. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any suggestions would be help and if you can provide some sample code would be great.

*I just want to force landscape orientation for one UIWebView.*

**EDIT:**

[image]

**Error:**

[image]

If its hard to read here is the error:

***Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [KM_T_World.MainViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES'***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement this in your View Controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    UIViewController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return [UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeLeft, UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeRight]
}
```

[image: settings]
[image: info]

Comment: thanks for the answer. But its still displaying in portrait orientation.

Comment: @user2190986  you should have Landscape turned on for the whole application in `Info.plist`. Then it works. Depending on how many ViewControllers you have and how many you want to be portrait-only I would recommend to implement portrait-only fixing in the ViewControllers or extend the whole class for the desired behavior.

Comment: thank you for the reply. how can I implement portrait fixing? Is it the same as above and just change landscape to portrait?

Comment: @user2190986  yes, just `return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait`

Comment: thank you so much for the reply. I have made an Edit in my question could you whether that is correct. I am trying to turn on landscape in info.plist

Comment: @user2190986  I've added screenshots to my answer.

Comment: I made the changes as you suggested and it works. My app starts in landscape and all views are in landscape. But as you suggested I tried to return UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait on my initial view and I get an error. I have edited my question with the error. I do apologise for so many questions.

Comment: @user2190986  please check if Portait checkbox is turned on and make sure `shouldAutorotate` func returns `true`.

Comment: Yes Portrait checkbox is turned On and shouldAutorotate fund returns true. Now the entire app is showing in portrait. nothing is in landscape anymore.

Comment: @user2190986  will do a sample project for you. stay tight.

Comment: Thank you so much. You are amazing. Thank you for the help.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you so much! You were amazingly helpful and apologies for so many questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.rawValue
    UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
}
```

And your Device orientation should be:

[image]

Result:

[image]

[Sample](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=60902703892985849195) for more Info.

**UPDATE:**

It is simple to lock orientation for particular view by adding this code:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask{

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your answer works but the only issue is by turning on the device orientation to landscape in Xcode settings will give the user the ability to rotate it device and change the orientation of all the views within the app. I only want to show one view in landscape and the remaining in portrait.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Your updated answer works well. But it works in all views except the UIWebView. It won't rotate it landscape. I rotates all other views well but not the UIWebView. Also it only works if the landscape option is checked in xCode

Comment: Don't use `supportedInterfaceOrientations ` in your `UIWebView` controller.

Comment: But the UIWebView controller is only one I want to rotate to landscape. Everything else should be Portrait. Any suggestions. I appreciate all the help. Thank you.

Comment: Try this updated project: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=05344327633237538198